# PostgreSQL query update returns UPDATE 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgis

I am having trouble with a PostgreSQL query where my update condition contains more prerequisites.

I attached 2 images to describe my problem.

I want to update the highlighted row

[image]

```
UPDATE locations
SET lat = 48.20325265836398, long = 16.34969524923078
WHERE prof_id = 58 AND lat = 47.5327567434237 AND long = 21.6292262077332
```

But the response is:

```
UPDATE 0 Query returned successfully in 58 msec.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post query and data as text, not images.

Comment: Unrelated: why are you storing coordinates with this level of precision? You're there in the realm of microscopy

Comment: Thank you, I added the code. The reason of this precise coordinate storing is that we will soon put a function in our app where you can see the services nearby on the map.

Comment: Fair enough, but I doubt that your "nearby" function would work with microns. Wouldn't metres/feet suffice?

Comment: Yes, you may be right. I didn't know how precise is this. Thanks for the advice I will cut down by a few precision points

Comment: @TamásTényi is there a particular reason as to why you chose to rollback my edit?

Comment: I wanted to apply it, but I must have clicked on the wrong button...

Comment: Yeah, now it is good. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be somewhere else (see this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d17783b2ce1e6af43f42d68dfc6aac53))

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE locations (
id INT, prof_id INT, lat NUMERIC, long NUMERIC);

INSERT INTO locations VALUES 
(57,58,47.5327567434237,21.6292262077332);

UPDATE locations SET lat = 48.20325265836398, long = 16.34969524923078 
WHERE prof_id = 58 AND lat = 47.5327567434237 AND long = 21.6292262077332;

SELECT * FROM  locations;

 id | prof_id |        lat        |       long        
----+---------+-------------------+-------------------
 57 |      58 | 48.20325265836398 | 16.34969524923078
(1 Zeile)
```

A few thoughts on your data:

- Reduce the [`level of precision`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674) of your coordinates. With 13 decimals you're in the realm of microns, which isn't very useful in geo applications. As you can see yourself, this level of precision it makes `=` queries quite challenging.
- Consider using [`PostGIS`](https://postgis.net/) to store your coordinates. It has over 1.3k kickass functions that make dealing with geospatial data very easy and efficient. It might seem complex in the beginning but believe me, it will definitely pay off on the long run!

Comment: Thank you, Jim. I am storing my lat and long values in double precision. You are right I need to lower the precision level, I don't need that precise coordinates. Now I changed it to numeric type and it worked. Thank you very much :))

Comment: @TamásTényi I'm glad it helped! Really consider using `geography` or `geometry` to store your coordinates. PostGIS just rocks ;)

Comment: One more question @Jim Jones. How many digits should I need after the decimal point to make it 10 metres precise?

Comment: @TamásTényi according to this post 4-5 digits would suffice ;) https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674

Answer (score 1):

Never assume that the decimal places you are seeing are the exact number that is stored in the table.

In your case, only `id` or `prof_id` is enough to update the row (as I can see from the attachments), so, no need of the `lat` and `long`, however in cases where you are forced to use the decimal numbers in comparison during update (and I will argue if this is the case you have bad design of the database tables), always round them to controllable decimal point as follows:

```
UPDATE locations SET 
       lat = 48.20325265836398, 
       long = 16.34969524923078 
WHERE  prof_id = 58 
       AND ROUND(lat,13) = 47.5327567434237 
       AND ROUND(long,13) = 21.6292262077332
```

Comment: As Jim mentioned before you are right, I will lower the precision level. The problem was I stored it in double precision now I changed to numeric and it works. Thank you for the advice.